# Spark Dataset with Json output comes out as Kryo encoded

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, kryo

I wanted to convert CSV data in a specific JSON format, not the usual flat thing. So I tried the following:

```
case class CityInfo(lat : Double, long : Double)
  case class City(name: String, country: String, info : CityInfo)


    implicit def kryoEncoder[A](implicit ct: ClassTag[A]) =
      org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.[A](ct)

    val cities = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("src/main/resources/worldcities.csv").cache()

    cities.map {
      case Row(city: String, _: Any, latStr : String, long : String, country: String, _*) =>
        City(city, country, CityInfo(latStr.toDouble, long.toDouble))
    }.write.json("data/testfile.json")
```

From this I would expect json lines with a nested object (like City and CityInfo). But I get lines like:

{"value":"AQBjb20uaGIuZXhlcmNpc2UuU3AxJENpdPkBAUtvc2927wEBY29tLmhiLmV4ZXJjaXNlLlNwMSRDaXR5SW5m7wFARXULDye7MEA0sJAt4A0bAVp1YmluIFBvdG/r"}

I used the Kryo encoder as it was failing to compile, so I found a stack overflow answer about it...not sure it's the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

And I found the solution by myself too quickly. 
So if you are using spark-shell or similar, you will have all the implicits in and nothing special is needed. But if, like me, you are writing a scala application from scratch you will need to add:

```
import spark.implicits._
```

this will add the implicit encoders. Also remove the Kryo thing. 
Note: the above example won't work as long (in CityInfo) generates an error for being a reserved word.